# How can I repair mongodb after changing dbPath?

Tags: mongodb

I have a following problem.

1. I have changed the path where I want to store my NOSQL db using `sudo joe /etc/mongod.conf`
2. `mongod.conf` is now:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /home/vojtam/disk/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

3. I want to run `sudo systemctl start mongod.service` and `sudo systemctl status mongod` I got

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-03-07 14:02:23 CET; 10s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 3013 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=100)
   Main PID: 3013 (code=exited, status=100)

bře 07 14:02:23 prace systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
bře 07 14:02:23 prace systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=100/n/a
bře 07 14:02:23 prace systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

4. I followed the advice here: [Mongod Service start exits with code 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45691032/mongod-service-start-exits-with-code-100) and I tried:
   `rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock` but there is not such file.

Can you help me please?

EDIT:

Here is my `mongod.log`:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T14:55:15.563+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"main","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T14:55:15.566+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T14:55:15.576+01:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T14:55:15.576+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T14:55:15.576+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":5332,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/home/vojtam/disk/mongodb","architecture":"64-bit","host":"prace"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T14:55:15.576+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.12","gitVersion":"51475a8c4d9856eb1461137e7539a0a763cc85dc","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu1804","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T14:55:15.576+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T14:55:15.576+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1","port":27017},"processManagement":{"timeZoneInfo":"/usr/share/zoneinfo"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/home/vojtam/disk/mongodb","journal":{"enabled":true}},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T14:55:15.578+01:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /home/vojtam/disk/mongodb"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T14:55:15.578+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":10000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T14:55:15.578+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T14:55:15.578+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T14:55:15.578+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T14:55:15.578+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T14:55:15.578+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T14:55:15.578+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T14:55:15.578+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T14:55:15.578+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T14:55:15.578+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T14:55:15.578+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T14:55:15.578+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T14:55:15.578+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T14:55:15.578+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T14:55:15.578+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T14:55:15.578+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}
```

Comment: Same as in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71338935/unable-to-run-mongo): Check the logfile `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

Comment: Check `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` file an see under which user `mongod` process is running. Most likely it is user `mongod`. Ensure this user has write access to `/home/vojtam/disk/mongodb`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thanks. Yes, it has the right to write there I think: `drwxrwxr-x  3 mongodb mongodb        4096 bře  7 14:36  mongodb`

Comment: Did you also check the parent directory, i.e. `/home/vojtam`? Typically the home directories are accessible only for the owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must grant write privileges to actual `dbPath` (in your case `/home/vojtam/disk/mongodb`) but also to all parent folders.

Home directories like `/home/vojtam` are usually accessible only for the owner, that's why they are called "home directory". The permissions of any sub-folder does not matter.

By default MongoDB process runs by user `mongod`, and typically a **service** is provided to **any user** of a system. Thus you should prefer a common folder for example `/var/lib/mongo` as used in [defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738322/what-is-the-default-database-path-for-mongodb/67043090#67043090).